# Cefsharp Flash plugin not supported

Tags: winforms, flash, cefsharp

I'm trying to get some flash content working within CefSharp v45. If I navigate to: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html it tells me

> Flash Player is pre-installed in Google Chrome, but not enabled.

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would install the system wide `PPAPI` version of `Flash`, as outlined

> A system-wide installation of Pepper Flash that will be automatically discovered and loaded by CEF on Windows and OS X can be downloaded from https://get2.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ (choose "FP for Opera and Chromium -- PPAPI") in Step 2). To enable use the system-wide installation pass the --enable-system-flash command-line argument.

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1586/add-pepper-flash-plugin-support#comment-16898332

Comment: That's a better solution than specifying a path. As you say, updating Chrome would require a settings change. I've installed the system wide player and removed the 'ppapi-flash-path' command line argument

Answer (score 1):

So this is how i solved it:

```
Dim settings As New CefSettings

    settings.CachePath = "cache"
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs("enable-system-flash") = "1"
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", "C: \Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\47.0.2526.111\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll") ' //Load a specific pepper flash version (Step 1 Of 2)
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
```

Make sure `InitializeComponent()` (for the form) is called after applying the settings.

Comment: The idea of using the existing plugin provided by `Chrome` is just an idea I was toying with. Upgrading to a newer version of `Chrome` will likely mean flash stops working unexpectedly. Ideally you would query the registry to locate the latest `Chrome` version. For systems without `Chrome` installed you'll have to use the `System Wide` installer as listed in my answer.